# What could be an abstracted name for a proposition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

We know that there's a difference between propositional logic and first order logic or predicate logic. Propositional logic concerns itself with propositions, which are statements or sentences that follows the principle of bivalence. On the other hand predicate logic is concerned about predicates, which are like an immature proposition (Immature because of the unknown value of some variable $x$ for any propositional function $p(x)$). If we can differentiate between compound propositions and propositions, then it's also possible to  identify a proposition involved in propositional logic by its atomicity.

Now if we abstract away everything about these propositions or predicates, and think of them as objects (As objects don't have any constant definition. It depends on any specific context.), how can we now make a distinction between objects of propositional logic and objects of predicate logic? Is there any specific terms for them?

For example, because the first object doesn't depend on anything, it could be called "independent" object, whereas the other could be "dependent" object or "x-dependent" object.

Also, I might've made one or many mistakes in this post, technically or terminologically, if so, please let me know.

Comment: [Atomic formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_formula): in propositional logic they are *sentential letters*: $P,Q, \ldots$, while in predicate logic they are *predicates* "filled with" *terms*: $P(x), R(a,b), \ldots$.

Comment: They are different objects according to the different syntactical specifications of the two language: in a nutshell, propositional logic provides a "coarse-grained" model of natural language, while predicate calculus provides a finer one.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. I see we can use words like "filled with"? This is something frequently I get troubled with. Many definitions include words that are part of our spoken language. But when I try to come up with something similar I get the feeling in my gut that something's not right. Which was the case with the question above. Does this mean as long as a definition or explanation is perceivably correct, I'm allowed to use any combination of words keeping the meaning intact?

Comment: Obviously is a "metaphor"... We have to think to a (unary) predicate symbol as something "unsatured": $\text {Philosopher}( \cdot)$. To have a sentence (a meaningful formula) we "fill it" with a "name" (a term): $\text {Socrates}$. The result is an atomic formula  $\text {Philosopher}(\text {Socrates})$ that is a sentence and thus have a truth value.

Comment: Having said that, it is not very clear to me if you are referring to the "syntactical" object: the string of symbols named *formula*, or the object of the world that usually is referred to as the meaning of a sentence/statement.

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that you are looking for an abstraction over expressions that are missing $n$ arguments to fill in to become an independent proposition? In that case, you can just go with the word "predicate" and treat propositions in PL as a special case of "zero-place predicates", $P()$.

Comment: @lemontree That was exactly what I was implying! I do understand your answer, but I'm looking for something that isn't dependent on any of the words (propositions or predicates). In other words, things that are unaware of the context. I am aware that my question may not hold much real value, but I'm trying to understand the terms or how things are named. What things are taken into considerations. Most terms in logic are very intuitive to understand, which made me question, can I come up with such terms myself? If so, then what'd be an incorrect name? The OC is me trying to mind the answers.

Comment: You said in your post that you are "looking for a specific term" -- 'predicate' is that term.